# PostgreSQL installation - error loading modules

Tags: postgresql, windows-xp, installation, postgis

I haven't been able to re-install PostgreSQL + PostGIS properly on our virtual server.
Installing PostgreSQL the following error occurs about the end of the process:

> "A non-fatal error occurred whilst loading database modules. Please check the installation log in C:...\Temp for details."

Here is what the log says:

```
Loading additional SQL modules...
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Programme\PostgreSQL\9.0\installer\server\loadmodules.vbs" "postgres" "****" "C:\Programme\PostgreSQL\9.0" "C:\Programme\PostgreSQL\9.0\data" 5432
Script exit code: 2

Script output:
 Installing the adminpack module in the postgres database...
Executing 'C:\DOKUME~1\Kiesow\LOKALE~1\Temp\rad3C00F.bat'...
Couldn't find the output file...
Failed to install the 'adminpack' module in the 'postgres' database
loadmodules.vbs ran to completion

Script stderr:
 Program ended with an error exit code

Error running cscript //NoLogo "C:\Programme\PostgreSQL\9.0\installer\server\loadmodules.vbs" "postgres" "****" "C:\Programme\PostgreSQL\9.0" "C:\Programme\PostgreSQL\9.0\data" 5432 : Program ended with an error exit code
```

Afterwards installation completes, I can start pgAdmin, log in and create new databases. Everything looks fine until I try to add PostGIS, using the stack builder wizard. Again the installation is almost finished, when:

> "Database creation failed."
>   "Would you like to view the error log " "create_templatepostgis_db_error.txt'?"

This error log doesn't exist. I might ignore the error and create the template db manually, which works. But I cannot use types like 'geometry', so I think, PostGIS is not yet usable.


Maybe anyone of you has got an idea of what I could have done wrong? Any hints? Can anybody help me to interpret the error log?


I use Windows XP, PostgreSQL 9.0 32bit (same with 8.4), PostGIS 1.5.
Postgres 8.3 + PostGIS was installed on this system earlier, but I uninstalled, deleted the data directory and let the installation wizard create a new posgres windows user.
Did a few reboots, too.
And I did choose a locale instead of [Default locale] at Postgres installation.


This is another part of the log I am suspicios of. It is right in the beginning. Maybe this helps:

```
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.0 Data Directory. Setting variable iDataDirectory to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.0 Base Directory. Setting variable iBaseDirectory to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.0 Service ID. Setting variable iServiceName to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.0 Service Account. Setting variable iServiceAccount to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.0 Super User. Setting variable iSuperuser to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.0 Branding. Setting variable iBranding to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.0 Version. Setting variable brandingVer to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.0 Shortcuts. Setting variable iShortcut to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.0 DisableStackBuilder. Setting variable iDisableStackBuilder to empty value
[15:44:31] Existing base directory: 
[15:44:31] Existing data directory: 
[15:44:31] Using branding: PostgreSQL 9.0
[15:44:31] Using Super User: postgres and Service Account: postgres
[15:44:31] Using Service Name: postgresql-9.0
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Kiesow\Lokale Einstellungen\Temp\prerun_checks.vbs"
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 The scripting host appears to be functional.

Script stderr:

Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Kiesow\Lokale Einstellungen\Temp\postgresql_installer\installruntimes.vbs" "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Kiesow\Lokale Einstellungen\Temp\postgresql_installer\vcredist_x86.exe"
Script exit code: 3010

Script output:
 Executing the runtime installer: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Kiesow\Lokale Einstellungen\Temp\postgresql_installer\vcredist_x86.exe
The runtime package exited with error code: 3010
```

Comment: It might have been a problem of the windows user. Somebody else installed it to our server without problems (and after deleting the user-account, again).

Answer (score 2):

From a command prompt, run this single command:

`C:\Programme\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe -p 5432 -U postgres -W -f C:\Programme\PostgreSQL\9.0\share\contrib\adminpack.sql postgres`

Its output may be more informative.  Running the above is all the `.vbs` is doing, incidentally.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for prompting this error message was due to because of localhost is pointing to some other machine.

Answer (score 0):

disable firewall and antivirus and try installing it again.